# Is it possible to edit a php file from itself?

Tags: php, file, text, content-management-system, edit

Is it possible to edit a php file from itself? I would like to have a php file that a user can log into with their e-mail address and password then give them a several fields they can edit. Upon submitting their entries the actual php file they used to submit info is updated.

Lets say there are three fields displayed once logged in...
 1. Email (can not be read when rendered in a browser or via source code)
 2. Password (can not be read when rendered in a browser or via source code)
 3. Textarea (contents you submit in the textarea would be visible if you load page in browser, in addtion, a blank username and password field would be visible in a browser, so the owner could login to edit the file)

With this system the user would be able to edit their login information and change information displayed on the page when viewed through a browser. Using the email in the file I guess I could include a sendmail function should they forget their password.

Is this possible. If so, does anyone know of a simple script that I can use to get started?

Comment: http://php.net/manual/en/function.file-put-contents.php is probably a good start.

Comment: your tag of *content management system* is where you should be looking

Comment: This sounds like an awful idea. Use a database, or even a data file (preferably outside your web space).

Answer (score 3):

You are are better off storing the information you want to change in another PHP file. Then loading/editing it on request.

Editing the file you are using can cause issues. You could also loose all of your code if something is injected that corrupts the formatting code.

Comment: or a db, but what he should really dfo is use an existing CMS

Comment: You would be better off storing the information in a database.

Comment: Strongly agree, never write to files that get executed by the server. Always do this in a controlled environment with a txt or crazy PHP/SQL wizardry

Comment: @SidneyLiebrand that last sentence doesn't really make sense.

Comment: @Dagon When I can't use a database I use arrays, encode them to JSON and save them in a php file to limit public access.

Comment: when can you never use a db?

Comment: Storing info in a database is not an option.

Comment: @CliffT If you want to store general info just use a .txt file. http://php.net/manual/en/function.file-put-contents.php This will save to a file, you just need to format the contents in a way that you can read it.

Comment: Dagon - this file would be uploaded to a client sites who have no knowledge of db. looking for a really easy system for them to update a small amount of info.

Comment: sounds like a perfect time to use SQLite

Comment: Thanks everyone for your comments. I will consider all your suggestions and welcome any other thoughts.